# How to render a ManyToMany Extra Field in my form? (E.g. quantity of each topping on my pizza)

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I wish to build an offer generator for my colleagues and I am a bit stuck. In an offer, we have 1 main product that can have many different accessories in different quantities. E.g. a Pizza with several toppings where you may have 1 x cheese, 2 x pepperoni, etc.

```
#models.py
class Accessory(models.Model):
    name              = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    price             = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

class Offer(models.Model):
    customer          = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    product           = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=True)
    accessories       = models.ManyToManyField(Accessory, through='Addons')

class Addons(models.Model):
    offer             = models.ForeignKey(Offer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    accessory         = models.ForeignKey(Accessory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity          = models.IntegerField(default=1)


#forms.py
class Offerform(ModelForm):
    accessories = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
                widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
                queryset=Accessory.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model   = Offer
        fields  = '__all__'
```

I have linked my offer accessories through a custom table (Addons) where I have specified the quantity. Nonetheless, how do I manage to get "quantity" as a field in my form so that I can select an accessory and specify the quantity?

Answer (score 0):

get only one filed name 
fields = ('quantity')

Comment: I don't understand?

Comment: If you want a particular filed that is quantity for you .This method can be used.